# Eval() problem in PHP

Tags: php

Quite some time ago I wrote a RSS parser. It worked fine until now, when I turned my error and notice reporting on. Currently I keep getting quite a lot of notices that tell me that something is wrong in the function. I tried solving this problem on my own, but I had no success. Could You please help me with this error?

The error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: RSS in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dropbox\RECtus\System\sysFiles\libarys\myRSSParser.lib(103) : eval()'d code on line 1

Notice: Undefined index: LINK in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dropbox\RECtus\System\sysFiles\libarys\myRSSParser.lib(103) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

The script:

```
function parseData($parser, $data) {
        if(!trim($data)) return;
        $RSS = '';
        $evalcode = "\$this->output";

        foreach($this->tags as $tag) {
            if(is_array($tag)) {
                list($tagname, $indexes) = each($tag);

                $evalcode .= "[\"$tagname\"]";
                if(!isset(${$tagname})) ${$tagname} = '';
                if(${$tagname}) $evalcode .= "[" . (${$tagname} - 1) . "]";
                if($indexes) extract($indexes); 
            } else {
                if(preg_match("/^([A-Z]+):([A-Z]+)$/", $tag, $matches)) {
                    $evalcode .= "[\"$matches[1]\"][\"$matches[2]\"]";
                } else {
                    $evalcode .= "[\"$tag\"]";
                }
            }
        }
        eval("$evalcode = $evalcode . '" . addslashes($data) . "';");
}
```

Line 103 is the eval() line.

Comment: Please provide a dump of `$evalcode` just before the `eval()`. Also, one of the two `$evalcode` strings in the `eval()` call should probably be escaped, e.g. `eval("\$evalcode = $evalcode . '" ...`

Comment: Eval is evil!  *(i.e. don't use eval)*

Comment: I would say the *real* problem is that you're using `eval()` in the first place. There are several XML parsers and a few RSS-specific XML parsers available for PHP ...  The best way to **really** solve your problem is not using `eval()`, it's notoriously hard to debug and prone to errors.

Comment: have you tried `echo` on eval argument to see what `eval()` tries to evaluate?

Comment: @jensgram: I'd say both.

Comment: [putting flame retardant suit on] code is crap. Abandon you "solution" entirely, and write a new one, you are looking for error in fatal error.

Comment: I can't wait until one of your `$tag`s is `;system("rm -rf /");`

Comment: Alright, the output is... `$this->output["RSS"]["CHANNEL"][0]["TITLE"]
$this->output["RSS"]["CHANNEL"][0]["LINK"]
$this->output["RSS"]["CHANNEL"][0]["DESCRIPTION"]`, but, if I shouldn't use this code, do you have any other suggestions? Because I could simply google this for a much crappier code. It's possible ;)

Comment: @Matīss Jānis Āboltiņš Being able to find worse code cannot be used to defend this code. Sorry :)

Comment: @jensgram oh, alright. Well, thank you all for the advice. :)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `eval()` ?

It seems you're just trying to concatenate portions of string, no ?

If so, why not just... [concatenate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) portions of [strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) ?

Basically, you should be able to do something like this :

```
$this->output = array();
$this->output['...'] = 'some string';
$this->output['...'] = array();
$this->output['...']['...'] = 'some other string';
```

Comment: This is not what his code is doing. It’s rather something like `$this->output[…] = $this->output[…].$data`.

Comment: @Gumbo : ergh, you're right! Thanks for your comment, I've edited my answer a bit :-)